# ecasound mixing and compression?

Tags: linux, audio

I chose ecasound as a tool for mixing a set of files and applying a simple amplitude compression. The sequence of operations should be:

```
combine inputs > apply compression > save to output file
```

The command I use is:

```
ecasound \
-a:1 -i input1.wav -ea:100 \
-a:2 -i input2.wav -ea:100 \
-a:3 -i input3.wav -ea:100 \
-a:4 -i input4.wav -ea:100 \
-a:all -o loop,1 \
-a:loop_chain -i loop,1 -ec:10,70\
-a:loop_chain -o output.wav
```

which works pretty fine and allows me to reduce significantly the chance of clipping. 
The problem is that I have ecasound installed both on my development machine (an iMac) and on my server (linux machine). On the iMac I installed ecasound v2.9.1 via the tarball, on the  linux machine I installed the same version trying via git, via tarball and via apt-get. In all three cases, there is a mismatch in the output WRT the output on the iMac. 
On the iMac I get this result (the desired one):
[image: waveform of the mac mix]
While on the linux machine I get:
[image: waveform of the linux mix]
Notice that the linux version is outputted directly to mp3 while the mac to WAV, but I also tried with WAV directly on linux and nothing changes. It looks like the file combining (mixing) on the linux machine performs some kind of automatic normalization. Documentation does not specifically refer to normalization, but in some forums and mailing lists it looks like it's a feature. This anyhow does not explain the mismatch and looks more like a configuration issue, even though in none of the two cases I explicitly changed and config nor upon installation nor later.

The ecasound debug output of the two cases doesn't show any difference either.

Any idea on how to make the Linux version work as the mac?

Note 1: even if the ecasound man pages say that the command -ec requires a value between 0 and 1, I actually found out that that value should be between 0 and 100.
Note 2: I tried using the -eca compressor but there I got other kind of issues, and I really would like to user just -ec.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a different default being used for the "-z:mixmode,sum" (versus -z:mixmode,avg , see ecasound(1) man page). This would explain the difference you are seeing.